# Как передать в метод нужный мне запрос?

Tags: c#

Ситуация простая. Есть метод GetData. Он получает все данные из БД и возвращает их.

```
public List<UserData> GetData(int FL)
{
    string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT id, guid, username, userblob, ""FL"" FROM ""USERS"" WHERE ""FL""={0};", FL);
    ...
            UserData ud = new UserData();
            ud.Id = dr[0].ToString();
            ud.Guid = (dr[1].ToString());
            ud.Name = (dr[2].ToString());
            ud.UserBlob = (byte[])dr[3];
            ud.FL = dr[4].ToString();
            uds.Add(ud);
    ...     
    return uds;
}
```

Однако у меня возникла потребность вызывать его передавая ему другую SQL команду `SELECT WHERE IN`.
Перавать ее в виде строки не могу т.к. у меня БД определены как абстракция:

```
        TargetDbContext = DbContextFactory.GetDbContext(_config.FirstDataBase);
        TransitDbContext = DbContextFactory.GetDbContext(_config.TransitDataBase);
```

Просто для каждой из используемых БД реализован свой метод: GetData и хотелось бы сам запрос определять в самом методе, а не передавать его снаружи. Как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте передавать флаг, вместо строки запроса.

Создаете `enum Query {Q1, Q2, Q3};`

```
public List<UserData> GetData(int FL, Query q)
{
    switch (q)
    {
        case Q1:
        {
            string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT id, guid, username, userblob, ""FL"" FROM ""USERS"" WHERE ""FL""={0};", FL);
            ...
            UserData ud = new UserData();
            ud.Id = dr[0].ToString();
            ud.Guid = (dr[1].ToString());
            ud.Name = (dr[2].ToString());
            ud.UserBlob = (byte[])dr[3];
            ud.FL = dr[4].ToString();
            uds.Add(ud);
            ...     
            return uds; 
            break;
        }
        case Q2:
        {
            string sql = string.Format("что-то другое");
            ...
            UserData ud = new UserData();
            ud.Id = dr[0].ToString();
            ud.Guid = (dr[1].ToString());
            ud.Name = (dr[2].ToString());
            ud.UserBlob = (byte[])dr[3];
            ud.FL = dr[4].ToString();
            uds.Add(ud);
            ...     
            return uds; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

При вызове функции - передавайте флаг, и тогда будет выполнятся правильная часть кода

Comment: Это тупиковый путь. На каждый чих придется создавать новый элемент `enum`, и переделывать код во всех `GetData`.

Comment: Какой есть выход?

Comment: @Igor насколько я понял - в автора 2 БД и 2 медота `GetData`. Так что вариант вполне рабочий в даной ситуации

Comment: Ну да, вроде бы сойдет. Вопрос только. Как передать в определение интерфейса, что он должен принимать?
` List<UserData> GetData(int FL, Query<T>);` Или как в C# это делается?

Comment: Просто он мне пишет вот что
http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/05/18/573c7609d1ac9.png
правда в самих методох я отправку Table еще не делал. Может он про это намекает?

Comment: `public enum Query {Q1, Q2, Q3};`